# How to dump DOM into a variable and detach it from document (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I need to do this:

```
var tempDoc;
$(tempDoc).load('<html>' + $(document).find('html').html() + '</html>');
```

and then do this:

```
$('body', tempDoc).css('background-color', '');
```

However when I do this, background-color removal also affects the $(document).
Is there a way to dump the $(document) into a temporary variable and change elements in it without affecting the $(document) itself?

Please let me know if this even make sense.

Comment: That's not really making sense to me. What are you going for?

Comment: yea i am confused as to what you need to achieve, maybe a different approach can be used

Comment: I need to post entire HTML to a PDF generator. So it's kind of like "Print to PDF" function on my web site. The way it works is you grab the entire HTML and post it to HTML-to-PDF generator app. But before that happens I what to modify the HTML on the fly (like to hide some elements). When I do, it also hides elements on my page. Hence the question.

Comment: Affects it with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I get this at all, but is there a reason you can't just do:

```
var tempDoc = $('html')​.clone();
$('body', tempDoc).css('background-color', 'green');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZTyqe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a documentFragment to dump the HTML to and then update the attributes without affecting the main document, like so.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.append($(document).html());
$('body', fragment).css('background-color', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).
it's exactly intended for that.

But It will have the same behaviour, because somehow (I don't understand exactly why) your manipulating the same body object.

The DocumentFragment is a good solution. Another one is to make a copy of your body, with [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), and to manipulate the copy.

You can then replace the original with your modified copy with [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

```js
var tempBody= $('body').clone(true);
tempBody.css('background-color', 'red');
$('body').replaceWith(tempBody);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nezXL/